# How to use a Gem with different config settings for my users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, square-connect

I am trying to use the square Connect gem but have a problem setting it up with a merchant scope.

This is what the documentation says: (https://github.com/square/connect-ruby-sdk)

```
# Load the gem
require 'square_connect'

# Setup authorization
SquareConnect.configure do |config|
  # Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: oauth2
  config.access_token = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN'
end

api_instance = SquareConnect::CatalogApi.new
```

The problem is that I need an `api_instance` per user I have with their own access token. What would the most appropriate solution be? Resetting the access token every time with some kind of lock, or setting multiple `api_instance` some way.

thanks!

Ideally I would have:

```
class User 
  def api_instance
    # the user scoped instance
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After briefly looking into the code of the gem, I think you should be able to create instances *ad hoc* as you need them. For example:

```
config = SquareConnect::Configuration.new do |config|
  config.access_token = 'some token'
end
api_client = SquareConnect::ApiClient.new(config)
api_instance = SquareConnect::CatalogApi.new(api_client)
```

Comment: Sweet, makes sense!